# Convert Json Object into String

Tags: c++, json

Here's my code snippet:

```cpp
#include <json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;

chat_message m; // helpter class to send the message

json j;
j["name"] = "States";
j["type "]= "Regular";
j["num"] = 4;

m.body_length( j.asString().size() ); // throws error on j.asString
```

I want to change this whole JSON object `j` to `std::string` and send it to the server.

How do I convert this object into `std::string`?
I tried using `asString`. I am new to this JSON things.

Comment: What is `chat_message`? What is `json`? What's the library you're using to parse json? Is it JsonCpp?

Comment: I have updated it .

Comment: Don't just randomly guess at function names, or read examples for the wrong library (`asString()` is from JsonCpp). Read the documentation for the library you're using! Study it!

Answer (score 7):

Serialize the JSON object to get an `std::string` using [`json::dump()`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a50ec80b02d0f3f51130d4abb5d1cfdc5.html#a50ec80b02d0f3f51130d4abb5d1cfdc5) method.

Always refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) first to understand the APIs of any library you're using.

Here's an example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/fzk5au)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    json j;
    j["name"] = "States";
    j["type"] = "Regular";
    j["num"] = 4;

    const auto s = j.dump(); // serialize to std::string
    std::cout << "JSON string: " << s << '\n';
    std::cout << "JSON size  : " << s.size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
JSON string: {"name":"States","num":4,"type":"Regular"}
JSON size  : 42
```

Answer (score 1):

The process of converting a JSON object to a string is called serialization.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#serialization--deserialization), the method you need to call is `j.dump()`.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
// explicit conversion to string
std::string s = j.dump();    // {"happy":true,"pi":3.141}

// serialization with pretty printing
// pass in the amount of spaces to indent
std::cout << j.dump(4) << std::endl;
// {
//     "happy": true,
//     "pi": 3.141
// }
```